# Visiting the sibling's family in the US

Tags: usa

Our sibling family lives in US and US citizens. We are Dutch.

I read:
https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-nl/niv/information/announcements#proclamation
https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/presidential-proclamation-coronavirus.html

And I'm not sure still if we can enter the US since the sibling's age is above 27 and he/she is married.

So, can we visit them?

If I can ask more questions here:

1. If we are both are eligible or only sibling relative?
2. If we are eligible do we need to go to the special process to get the exception?
3. If we go to the process would be two birth certificates (they are translated and have apostille) enough for the exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot make this trip at the current time.

Entry from the Schengen area is generally banned, by the proclamation you mentioned. The full text of the proclamation is available [here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/25/proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-non-immigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease/), and lists several exceptions. There's only one exception where a sibling relationship is relevant:

> (v)     any noncitizen who is the sibling of a U.S. citizen or lawful permanent resident, provided that both are unmarried and under the age of 21;

You said your sibling is 27 and married, so this is not applicable to you. None of the other exceptions appear to be relevant to your situation, based on the information in your question.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I mentioned 27 since there is 21 in the text. After reading that text one more time I understand that we don't comply with the exception.